# Is it compulsory for the wicket-keeper to wear pads?

Tags: rules, cricket

Why does the wicket-keeper wear pads in cricket? Is it a rule, or is it a choice they make?

Answer (score 5):

No, the wicket-keeper is not required to wear pads. To quote from [Law 40.1](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-40-the-wicket-keeper/):

> The wicket-keeper is the only fielder *permitted* to wear gloves and external leg guards.

(my emphasis) Note that's "permitted" not "required". As for why, that's simple - being hit on the shins by a cricket ball *hurts*.